# Select by month sql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i have this date `2021-08-19`,
i want to select by month all my data from my table where dateC = ( extract month).
**EXEMPLE QUERY**

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE dateC= extract month "08" from(2021-08-19)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
where year(dateC) = year('2021-08-19') and
      month(dateC) = month('2021-08-19')
```

If you just want the month regardless of year, then:

```
where month(dateC) = month('2021-08-19')
```

Or

```
where date_format(dateC, '%Y%m') = date_format('2021-08-19', '%Y%m')
```

Neither of these are index friendly.  That requires a little more work.  Let met call your date `@date`:

```
where dateC >= @date + interval (1 - day(@date)) day and
      dateC < (@date + interval (1 - day(@date)) day) + interval 1 month
```

Note:  all of the above work if there is a time component.  If `dateC` is really a date with no time component, then:

```
where dateC > last_day(@date - interval 1 month) and
      dateC <= last_day(@date)
```

Comment: I want to ask if we can use something like (LIKE '%') in SQL, instead of this , because in my front End i will give the month number

Comment: @yasuenLEdzi . . . No.  `LIKE` is an operator on strings.  Your column is a date, so you should be using date functions.

Comment: So , in my case how can i select my data with the number of month , For example when i put 08 , my query will search in the date column all the months = 08

Comment: @yasuenLEdzi . . . I added in a solution for the month regardless of year.  You need to be careful when doing that, because you might end up mixing data from different years.